Trigger Power Automate via Power Apps to mail Sharepoint list as csv (Filter Query)
I have a SharePoint list and one of the columns is Status which only can be Active, Inactive or N/A. I created my Power Automate which is triggered by Power Apps to create a CSV file and send a mail to the user. then decided to add Combobox into my PowerApps as Filter. cause, people can filter or do not filter or can filter the list on multiple choice. Like only Actives or Inactives and N/A s or for all. So, on filter query on power automate I wrote multiple codes and not succeeded. IS there any one can guide me?

To filter your SharePoint list based on the Status column in Power Automate, you can use the OData filter syntax in your flow. Since you want to allow users to filter by multiple choices (Active, Inactive, N/A), you can construct your filter query accordingly.
Here’s a general approach you can take:

Combobox in Power Apps: Ensure that your Combobox in Power Apps is set up to allow multiple selections. This will enable users to select one or more statuses.

Pass Filter Values to Power Automate: When you trigger Power Automate from Power Apps, pass the selected values from the Combobox as parameters.

Construct OData Filter Query: In Power Automate, you can construct your filter query using the values received from Power Apps. For example, if you receive a list of selected statuses, you can create a filter query like this:
Status eq 'Active' or Status eq 'Inactive' or Status eq 'N/A'
If you are dynamically building this based on user selection, you can concatenate the conditions based on the selected values.

Use the Filter Query in the Get Items Action: In your "Get items" action in Power Automate, use the constructed filter query in the Filter Query field.


